# Setting the value of an html element programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create auto responder message templates with respect the the subject the visitor chooses.  I checked formmail and I found how it's done as in setting up templates to be picked up from fmtemplate directory.

http://www.tectite.com/fmhowto/autorespond.php

However, before the auto-responder sends anything, I'd need to check the "Subject" selection and send the appropriate auto-responder template.

The way I think it should be done is as follows.  Have the values of the select tag set like the following.

```
<select name="subject" id="subject" class="subject_category"">
    <option value="first_option">First Option</option>
    <option value="second_option">Second Option</option>
    <option value="third_option">Third Option</option>
    <option value="fourth_option">Fourth Option</option>
</select>
```

And some how have the following hidden tag instructed by formmail

to replace the file name of the autorespond HTML into the option chosen by the user.

Is there a way to embed javascript in place of arhtml.html file so it reads off the select option and constructs a html name accordingly?

Comment: You want to change the form action?  Where do you want to put the "html name?"